# parsing JSON data with some sort of data tag

Tags: json, swift

Im trying to get this json into an array like this:

```
struct WeatherData{

    var timezone: timezone?
    var offset: Int?
    var temperature: Double
    var summary: String
    var WeatherIcon: icon
    var precipIcon: precipIcon
    var time: Double
    var precipIntensity: Double?
    var precipProbability: Double
    var precipProbabilityPercentage: Int
    var windSpeed: Double
    var humidity: Double
    var precipTypeText: String
}

struct WeatherDataArray{

    var weeklyWeather: [WeatherData]?

}
```

Specifically i want the weather from "daily", but the "data =" tag is in the way

But im wondering how i can get around the "data = " tag. What is it? is there a special way to deal with these? Do i have to play with the string and remove the first x letters? and the ending bracket in the end of the array?

```
["latitude": 10, "longitude": 10, "offset": 1, "timezone": Africa/Lagos, "flags": {
    "isd-stations" =     (
        "650550-99999",
        "651340-99999"
    );
    sources =     (
        gfs,
        cmc,
        fnmoc,
        isd
    );
    units = si;
}, "daily": {
    data =     (
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "32.8";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1478872800;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "16.45";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1478833200;
            cloudCover = "0.23";
            dewPoint = "0.43";
            humidity = "0.22";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.38";
            ozone = "256.32";
            precipIntensity = 0;
            precipIntensityMax = 0;
            precipProbability = 0;
            pressure = "1010.07";
            summary = "Partly cloudy until afternoon.";
            sunriseTime = 1478841279;
            sunsetTime = 1478883373;
            temperatureMax = "35.52";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1478872800;
            temperatureMin = "16.45";
            temperatureMinTime = 1478833200;
            time = 1478818800;
            windBearing = 13;
            windSpeed = "1.84";
        },
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "34.37";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1478955600;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "14.67";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1478923200;
            cloudCover = "0.22";
            dewPoint = "2.07";
            humidity = "0.26";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.42";
            ozone = "255.7";
            precipIntensity = 0;
            precipIntensityMax = 0;
            precipProbability = 0;
            pressure = "1009.42";
            summary = "Partly cloudy in the morning.";
            sunriseTime = 1478927700;
            sunsetTime = 1478969769;
            temperatureMax = "37.03";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1478955600;
            temperatureMin = "14.67";
            temperatureMinTime = 1478923200;
            time = 1478905200;
            windBearing = 42;
            windSpeed = "1.41";
        },
                {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "34.63";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1479045600;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "15.27";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1479006000;
            cloudCover = "0.39";
            dewPoint = "1.76";
            humidity = "0.24";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-night";
            moonPhase = "0.46";
            ozone = "253.31";
            precipIntensity = 0;
            precipIntensityMax = 0;
            precipProbability = 0;
            pressure = "1008.89";
            summary = "Mostly cloudy starting in the afternoon.";
            sunriseTime = 1479014121;
            sunsetTime = 1479056166;
            temperatureMax = "37.37";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1479045600;
            temperatureMin = "15.27";
            temperatureMinTime = 1479006000;
            time = 1478991600;
            windBearing = 36;
            windSpeed = "2.22";
        }]
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: is your json is in correct format??? Because now I validated it using online json validator it says as invalid json, so first check that, then we can come up for solution.

Comment: @LordFresh could you check your  json format here ?https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: @Karthick Im pretty new at this so im unsure what part to show you guys. I edited it down a bit cause i didnt think the format was an issue.

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject]
                        print(json)

Is this part helpful? I thought this was the json part cause it makes it into a jsonObject, but maybe you want the data im sending into JSONSerialization? Pardon my ignorance

Comment: @NazmulHasan I use your link, paste in my request "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/fdb7fc33b542deec6680877abc34465a/10.0,10.0?units=si" and then I get a response which looks like JSON to me, but it says invalid. Any advice?

Comment: @LordFresh well .just past your json not link at this situation

Comment: @NazmulHasan its too big. 40k characters. And also the validators wont validate it. Isnt the json what i get out from doing: 

et json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject] print(json)